# BashScript. Como executar um comando em determinada hora?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

Estou tentando criar um código em Bash Scripting, e preciso que ele execute esse script em segundo plano e execute esse comando diariamente nesse horário predeterminado e execute somente uma vez.
Estou tendo problemas, pois ele fica dando loop's infintos, exemplo dando o comando 'id'.
Aqui está o código:

```
#!/bin/bash

RUNT="15:07"
exec='id'

while [ 1 ]
do
    DATE=`/bin/date +%H:%M`
    if [ $DATE. = $RUNT. ]
    then
        $exec
    fi
done &
```

Answer (score 2):

Você deve usar *cron*. Para isso, você deve editar o seu arquivo *crontab*. Utilize:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

E insira o seguinte conteúdo:

```
07 15 * * * /Path/to/your/script.sh
```

Ele irá executar o script todos os dias, às 15:07. Para entender mais como a sintaxe *cron* funciona, você pode consultar [este website](https://crontab.guru/#07_15_*_*_*).

Answer (score 0):

Para realizar este tipo de tarefa, se utiliza o cron (crontab|crond)
de uma olhada no primeiro resultado de exemplo que achei no google: https://tecadmin.net/crontab-in-linux-with-20-examples-of-cron-schedule/